# Write a join query in yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2, inner-join

I want write a join query in yii2 format.The query which we write in joinWith function joins the table with main table not with the inner table that are mentioned in the joins

```
select table1.id,table1.name
from
table1
inner join
table2
on
table1.id=table2.id
inner join
table3
on
table2.id=table3.id
```

Comment: Which models are involved ..?

Comment: Can you provide what query you wrote using joinWith ? It would be much easier do imporve it rather than make new query

Answer (score 0):

Here Example simple way will Produce in array

```
$list= Yii::app()->db->createCommand('select table1.id,table1.name
                                    from table1
                                        inner join table2
                                        on table1.id=table2.id
                                        inner join table3 
                                        on table2.id=table3.id')->queryAll();

$rs=array();
foreach($list as $item){
    //process each item here
    $rs[]=$item['id'];

}
return $rs;
```

in yii format

```
JOIN_TYPE = INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN, FULL OUTER JOIN etc
$query = new Query;
$query  ->select(['SELECT COLUMNS'])  
        ->from('TABLE_NAME_1')
        ->join( 'JOIN_TYPE', 
                'TABLE_NAME_2',
                'TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN =TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN'
            ); 
$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
```